# ASP.Net Multi image upload .net compatible commercial control

Tags: c#, asp.net

We are currently planning on trying to allow a user to be able to select multiple images to upload to an ASP.NET website. Can anyone give me some suggestions as to which commercial and free controls which we can use?

Requirements would be that:

- is browser independent (works on IE, Firefox, Chrome, etc. without requiring extra download)
- allows user to preview image(s) before selecting
- easy to integrate into asp.net
  solution.
- a non javascript control (would prefer a c# based solution)
- good API
- UI easy to change
- simple to develop with

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[jQuery - Uploadify:](http://www.uploadify.com/)

I've used this, and it's fantastic.  Not sure if it lets you preview images prior to upload, but it's still a great tool and pretty easy to setup.

Comment: thanks i have looked at this control and it seems very good. i think we are going to go with this. thanks

Comment: If you need any help, how the HTTPhandlers should be setup, etc.. let me know.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it is possible to have user select more than one file to upload without using some sort of plug in like Silverlight or Flash.

If you decide to go with Silverlight you might want to check out [Telerik's Silverlight](http://www.telerik.com/products/silverlight.aspx) controls. I have used their multifile uploader successfully on a web app for uploading multiple pictures. I extended it to include a preview feature. Works well. Would be happy to send you my code if you decide to go the Silverlight/Telerik route.

Answer (score 2):

Try [Aurigma Image Uploader](http://www.aurigma.com/Products/ImageUploader/). It requires Java however.

Answer (score 0):

For the record, the Telerik Upload control for ASP.NET now includes three "modes:"

- **Standards:** Uses normal HTML file upload (single file at a time, requires postback)
- **Silverlight:** Automatically renders Telerik Silverlight upload control
- **Flash:** Automatically renders Flash upload control

You only need to configure the single ASP.NET upload, and if the plug-ins are available, you can offer your users a "premium" experience (multifile upload, drag-and-drop to upload, and even [multiple files in a single post](http://blogs.telerik.com/silverlightteam/posts/10-06-25/silverlight_upload_control_just_got_better.aspx).) This is great from a progressive enhancement (or graceful degradation) design perspective, too, since it allows you to easily address users with and without rich browser plug-ins.

For a simple async upload, I've also used jQuery in the past. Specifically, "[Ajax Upload](http://valums.com/ajax-upload/)" by Andrew Valums. It uses the IFRAME-hack to simulate async file uploads, but it's easy to setup and use.

Hope these options help.